# Code works fine on Mac/Windows, but not linux?

Tags: python, linux, decode, encode, revit-api

I've written a pretty simple code to determine the version of a Revit file. For those that are not aware, there is no way to tell what "Revit year" (i.e. 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023) a .rvt file is in without it either -

- being in the name of the file
- opening the file in notepad and searching for something along the lines of "Format: 2022"
  So I've written a code for it on my windows computer. The code is below.

```
import shutil
import os
import re

rvt_file = 'revit_file_2020.rvt'
if '.rvt' in rvt_file:
    new_f = rvt_file.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
    shutil.copyfile(rvt_file, new_f)
    content = open(new_f, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
    new_s = ""
    for char in content:
        if char.isalpha() or char.isdigit() or char == ":":
            new_s += char
    if "build" in new_s.lower():
        ind = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('build', new_s.lower())] 
        new_s = new_s[ind[0]-60:ind[0]+40]
        ind = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('format', new_s.lower())][0]
        new_s = new_s[ind:ind+15]
        rvt_version = ""
        for char in new_s:
            if char.isdigit():
                rvt_version += char
        
        print(f"Revit Version: {rvt_version}")
        
    else:
        print("not found")
else:
    print("Please send a revit file instead.")
```

This code works great on windows and mac, but for some reason it will not work on linux for me. It will create the .txt file just fine, but cannot find any of the query words I search for when the txt file is opened. I am trying to incorporate this into a simple discord server that's hosted on linux.
I have a feeling that it has to do with the way windows and mac create/read the .txt file it creates. I tried using an encoding system different than utf-8, but that didn't work.
Any idea what could be so different on linux and how I could alter the code to run there?

For anyone wanting to test it out, I've provided some revit files here:
https://send.johnprovost.com/download/822837095733c2d1/#8rZThFq4UGqc2mOpK6w9PQ

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when it "does not run" on Linux?

Comment: Mac and Linux are much more similar in this respect than Windows - and you are oppeining the files as binary and ignoring the characters that might differ (line-ending) anyway, 

So, I'd say you are having a permission problem with this code, unrelated to the code itself: can it create  a file copy in the  "running directory" in the linux box? Using the `tmpfile` library in Python to ensure you copy your file to a place you can write woud likely solve this.

Comment: Other than that, simply reading the file and matching a proper regexps - with 3 lines of code, would also fix it. You likely don't need 95% of this code at all.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing how you end up solving this! Thx!